# Spring Boot Cucumber tests could not resolve placeholder 'random.uuid'

Tags: java, spring-boot, random, cucumber, spring-boot-test

I want a Spring Boot property to have an impossible to guess random value by default (for security reasons), so I am trying to use a [random UUID](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-random-values) as the default value, using code like this:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
...
   @Autowired
   public UserServiceImpl(@NonNull final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            @NonNull final UserRepository userRepository,
            @NonNull @Value("${administrator.password:${random.uuid}}") final String administratorPassword) {
      ...
   }
```

But my Cucumber Spring Boot tests are complaining about the `${random.uuid}` thus:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in file [.../UserServiceImpl.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'random.uuid' in value "administrator.password:${random.uuid}"
```

What do I have to do to get my application to use a random property value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be related to test slicing. If I run a clean Spring boot project's test with:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Value("${nonexistingValue:${random.uuid}}")
    private String someVal;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        assertThat(someVal).contains("-");
    }

}
```

The test passes. However, if I change `@SpringBootTest` to `@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})` or `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, the test fails. `${random.uuid}` and similar expressions should be available in a normal runtime environment.

---

Because of this slicing, it seems that the `RandomValuePropertySource` is not available. A rather inelegant work-around is to explicitly add it to the context, using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean created in your test context:

```
@Configuration
public class CucumberBeansConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      final var configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
      final var sources = new MutablePropertySources();
      sources.addFirst(new RandomValuePropertySource());
      configurer.setPropertySources(sources);
      return configurer;
   }

}
```

Comment: This sounds like the most likely explanation. In such a case perhaps `RandomValuePropertySource` is not available?

Comment: Yes, that could very well be. Some beans will not be instantiated in a test setup to speed up the test process, and the RandomValuePropertySource might be one of those beans.

Answer (score 0):

`${random.uuid}` can only be used if [`RandomValuePropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/RandomValuePropertySource.html) is available.

As workaround, you can define a "dummy default value" and detect this in your code:

```
   @Autowired
   public UserServiceImpl(@NonNull final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            @NonNull final UserRepository userRepository,
            @NonNull @Value("${administrator.password:no-default-vale-provided}") final String administratorPassword) {
      this.adminPassword = "no-default-value-provided".equals(administratorPassword)
              ? UUID.randomUUID().toString()
              : administratorPassword;
   }
```

---

If you have [`RandomValuePropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/RandomValuePropertySource.html) available, then the SpEL expression `${random.uuid}` should indeed resolve to a random UUID. `${…}` is a property placeholder and `#{$…}` is SpEL syntax.

You need to change your annotation:

```
@NonNull @Value("#{${administrator.password} ?: ${random.uuid}}") final String administratorPassword
```

Answer (score -1):

Cucumber uses Springs `TestContextManager`. By annotating your context configuration with `@CucumberContextConfiguration` Cucumber knows which class use to start the test context.

```
import com.example.app;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {

}
```

Do make sure the `CucumberSpringConfiguration` is on the `cucumber.glue` path.