# Mocking a configuration property when testing a Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have a Spring bean that reads a configuration property value from `application.yml`

```
public class AutoDisableRolesService {

    @Value("${cron.enabled}")
    private boolean runTask;
    // remainder of class omitted
}
```

In the application.yml this property is set to false

```
cron:
  enabled: false
```

But when I run the test, I want it to be true. I've tried the following, but it does not seem to work

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "cron.enabled=true" })
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AutoDisableRolesServiceTests {
    
    @Mock
    private UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private AutoDisableRolesService autoDisableRolesService;
    // remainder of test class omitted
}
```

I've also tried the following, without success

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AutoDisableRolesService.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "cron.enabled=true")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AutoDisableRolesServiceTests {

    @Mock
    private UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private AutoDisableRolesService autoDisableRolesService;
    // remainder of test class omitted
}
```

Comment: Try using a [@TestPropertySource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source)

Comment: @Michiel any chance you could flesh that out into an answer?

Comment: I've misread your initial question, it isn't related to test properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up two types of test set ups; A Spring boot test setup with a Mockito test set up. By using `@InjectMocks` on your class under test, Mockito instantiates the class and injects all the fields annotated with `@Mock`, bypassing the Spring TestApplicationContext setup.

Either use a Spring test set up using:

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "cron.enabled=true" })
public class AutoDisableRolesServiceTests {
    
    @MockBean
    private UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AutoDisableRolesService autoDisableRolesService;

    // remainder of test class omitted
}
```

Or a mockito set up using:

```java
public class AutoDisableRolesServiceTests {
    
    @Mock
    private UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private AutoDisableRolesService autoDisableRolesService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(autoDisableRolesService, "runTask", true);
    }
}
```

[edit]

If you don't need a full @SpringBootTest set up, use

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties={"cron.enabled=true"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AutoDisableRolesService.class})
public class AutoDisableRolesServiceTests {
    
    @MockBean
    private UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AutoDisableRolesService autoDisableRolesService;

    // remainder of test class omitted
}
```

The difference between @SpringBootTest and @ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class) is that a @SpringBootTest loads the full (test)ApplicationContext while the latter only loads a partial context, which is faster but doesn't include everything.

Comment: How would I inject `AutoDisableRolesService` and mock its depenencies when using the third approach?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, would you be able to add a line or two explaining the difference between the `SpringBootTest` and `SpringExtension` approaches?

Comment: It seems you can load a partial application context with `@SpringBootTest(classes = {AutoDisableRolesService.class})` or by combining `@SpringBootTest` with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AutoDisableRolesService.class})`. I wonder if there's any difference between these approaches and `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` ?

Comment: The difference is that, while both set ups you mention only include the given class, a SpringBootTest als loads additional configuration you would have in a normal ApplicationContext  (also known as test slices).  For instance, in a non-SpringBootTest, a [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64880136/2148365) is not automatically loaded.